# The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysaltfiles', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

Here is the query that iam trying to run on my SQL Management Studio 2008 R2:

```
USE master
GO
if exists (select * from sysdatabases where name='Northwind')
    drop database Northwind
go

DECLARE @device_directory NVARCHAR(520)
SELECT @device_directory = SUBSTRING(filename, 1, CHARINDEX(N'master.mdf', LOWER(filename)) - 1)
FROM master.dbo.sysaltfiles WHERE dbid = 1 AND fileid = 1

EXECUTE (N'CREATE DATABASE Northwind
 ON PRIMARY (NAME = N''Northwind'', FILENAME = N''' + @device_directory + N'northwnd.mdf'')
 LOG ON (NAME = N''Northwind_log'',  FILENAME = N''' + @device_directory + N'northwnd.ldf'')')
go

exec sp_dboption 'Northwind','trunc. log on chkpt.','true'
exec sp_dboption 'Northwind','select into/bulkcopy','true'
GO
```

And here is complete error am getting on my screen:

```
 The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysaltfiles', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
 CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
Msg 15010, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dboption, Line 64
 The database 'Northwind' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases. 

 Msg 15010, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dboption, Line 64
The database 'Northwind' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases.
```

Looks like permissions are messed up. But i can't figure out what to do. Please a well explained answer with step by step guidance would be very appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Login as a user with `sysadmin` server role, e.g. as `sa` if your server configured for SQL Server Authentication mode.

Answer (score 0):

enter the all domain name to the connection string to the data source ...data source=dbname.doma.main.local